# why this image is not full sized?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make this image full size but why some space is remaining right side

CSS/HTML

```css
/* Header */

.header {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header .header-content {
  padding-top: 15.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.header .text-container {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="content">

  <!-- start of header -->
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="header-content"> //here give an class of that image
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="text-container">
              <h1><span class="turquoise">StartUp Landing</span> Page Template Free</h1>
              <p class="p-large">Use Evolo free landing page template to promote your business startup and generate leads for the offered services</p>
              <a class="btn-solid-lg page-scroll" href="#services">DISCOVER</a>
            </div>
            <!-- end of text-container -->
          </div>
          <!-- end of col -->
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1088" alt="alternative">
            </div>
            <!-- end of image-container -->
          </div>
          <!-- end of col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of row -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of header-content -->
  </header>
  <!-- end of header -->

</div>
```

[image]

I want to set this full image right side(question mark)

which place need correction

Comment: The [`.container`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#containers) class limits the width of the content. Use `container-fluid`, or remove the class if you want the content to span full width.

Comment: You may use picsum.photos or dummyimage.com or else for you snippet demonstrating your code and issue ;)

Comment: @Turnip problem is sovled I remove the ```<div id="container-fluid">```

Answer (score 0):

add the width and height to body and html in head.

```
html,body {
width:100%;
height:100%
}

.img-fluid{
width:100%
height:100%
}

.image-container{
width:<!--as you wish--> 20px;
height:<!--as you wish--> 20px;
}
```